# Tikz: Angle arc overrunning line

Tags: tikz-pgf

I drew two interecting lines and the angle of the arc between but the arc is overrunning the line. What am I doing wrong?

The code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (origin) at (0,0);
\draw [thick] (-2,2) coordinate (topy) -- (2,-2.5) coordinate (line1);
\draw[thick] (-3,-2) coordinate (line2) -- (3,2);
\pic [draw, -, "$\theta$", angle eccentricity=1.5] {angle = line2--origin--line1};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: Remember to supply compilable code, so that people who wants to help does not need to spend time on finding the needed packages.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your lines does not cross at origin. I do not know what you want!? So I just show how to see the problem:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border = 0.5 cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary {angles,quotes}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (origin) at (0,0);
\draw [thick] (-2,2) coordinate (topy) -- (2,-2.5) coordinate (line1);
\draw[thick] (-3,-2) coordinate (line2) -- (3,2);
\pic [draw, -, "$\theta$", angle eccentricity=1.5] {angle = line2--origin--line1};
\fill (line1) circle (0.05);
\fill (origin) circle (0.05);
\fill (line2) circle (0.05);
\end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}
```

[image: circles at named coordinates]

With circles at the named coordinates, it can be seen that the angle correctly spans the arc `line2--origin--line1`.

Comment: Right, I just noticed the mistake with the origin and was going to delete the question. But since it's been answered perhaps it can help someone else!

Answer (score 5):

To me it is always helpful to color everything, so I can see what is happening. Your example is missing an intersection:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{angles,quotes,intersections}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (origin) at (0,0);
\draw [thick] (-2,2) coordinate (topy) -- (2,-2.5) coordinate (line1);
\draw[thick] (-3,-2) coordinate (line2) -- (3,2);
\pic [draw, -, "$\theta$", angle eccentricity=1.5] {angle = line2--origin--line1};
\end{tikzpicture}

% Improved example
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[thick,name path=A,red] (-2,2) coordinate (A) -- (2,-2.5) coordinate (B);
  \draw[thick,name path=B,green] (-3,-2) coordinate (C) -- (3,2) coordinate (D);
  \path[name intersections={of=A and B,name=inter}];
  \draw pic["$\theta$", draw=blue, angle eccentricity=1.5] {angle=C--inter-1--B};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

See your attempt at the top and mine below:

[image: named paths with intersection]